How to append a symbol to user input and allow backspace once appended (to ignore it)
I have a field where the user can enter a number, and I'm trying to append a % symbol to it as the user types.
I've done it, but as soon as it appears, the user can no longer use the backspace key, as they're now technically trying to remove the % symbol.
Is there a way to have the % symbol be ignored, so that the user can backspace through it?
Here is what I've done:


const goalMarginInput = document.getElementById('goal-margin');

function handleGoalMarginInput(event) {
    const input = event.target;
    let value = input.value.replace('%', '');  // Remove existing % symbol

    if (!isNaN(value) && value.trim() !== '') {
        value += '%';  // Append % symbol
    }

    input.value = value;
}

goalMarginInput.addEventListener('input', handleGoalMarginInput);
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Goal Margin Input Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="goal-margin">Know your goal profit margin?</label>
    <input type="text" id="goal-margin" placeholder="Goal margin">
</body>
</html>



You'll be able to see what I mean - its a poor user experience to not be able to backspace if you've typed the wrong number.
Thanks!

why do you need to append % while editing? What do you try to do?

originally wanted the % symbol fixed to the right of the input field, but somewhere my formatting messed up and it was floating halfway down the page, so thought this could achieve the same type of thing.

This is hard to do, because you essentially have to take over all the input editing from the browser. Just put the % after the input field, e.g. <input type="number" name="percentage">%

As long as you have no whitespace between <input> and %, it won't float away.

Either that or make use of an input masking plugin. Don't try to implement it yourself.

Maybe you can add another keydown eventListener for Backspace key to delete the last iput character

I am not sure but maybe this can be another way you can use to still be able to delete last character using Backspace key


const goalMarginInput = document.getElementById('goal-margin');

function handleGoalMarginInput(event) {
    const input = event.target;
    let value = input.value.replace('%', '');  // Remove existing % symbol

    if (!isNaN(value) && value.trim() !== '') {
        value += '%';  // Append % symbol
    }

    input.value = value;
}


function checkBackspace(e){
    if(e.key ==='Backspace') {
        let newInputVal = goalMarginInput.value.substr(0,goalMarginInput.value.length-1)
        goalMarginInput.value = newInputVal
    }
}

goalMarginInput.addEventListener('input', handleGoalMarginInput);
goalMarginInput.addEventListener('keydown', checkBackspace);
    <label for="goal-margin">Know your goal profit margin?</label>
    <input type="text" id="goal-margin" placeholder="Goal margin">




brilliant - works like a charm!!! thank you :)

You are very welcome! Enjoy coding
